# How to pass an explict Null vaule using Boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-simple-email-service

Is there a way to make a boto3 client pass a parameter with an explict null value (as opposed to omitting the parameter entirely)?

I'm trying to use [create_recipt_rule on the boto3 SES client](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.create_receipt_rule) to add a new receipt rule that I want to be the first rule.

The AWS API docs (also pulled through to boto docs above) say this should be achieved by passing the `After` parameter with a null value:

> After (string) -- The name of an existing rule after which the new rule will be placed. If this parameter is null, the new rule will be inserted at the beginning of the rule list

From testing I've found that this must be explictly passed as `null`. Simply ommiting the `After` parameter results in the rule being added at the end of the list.

I thought I'd be able to pass an explict value by having the `After` parameter present with an explit `None` value. However this fails on boto3's parameter validation. i.e.

```
client.create_receipt_rule(
  RuleSetName='my-ruleset',
  After=None,
  Rule={ ... },
)
```

Results in the following error:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter After, value: None, type: <type 'NoneType'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>
```

I also tried passing the string `'null'` but that looks for a rule called `null` to put the rule after rather than putting the rule at the start.

Is there a way to pass an expit `null` value to a parameter via the boto3 client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out my test was incorrect and so I miss-understood how `create_receipt_rule` behaves when the `after` parameter is omitted.

When the `after` parameter is omitted the new rule is added as the first rule, not the last as I thought.

So the answer to this question is there is no need to pass an explict `null` value, just omitting the `after` parameter achieves the goal.